# Java Webcam Capture Photo And Display

Tags: java, webcam, photo

Can you tell me simple way to use a webcam in Java and capture a photo and display it or could you tell me where can I read something about it.

Comment: Try doing some research! ... Also, before you post questions, read the  [help/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page!

Comment: Of course, I have post the question, after researching, please, just answer if you know

Comment: Here, people only know how to say that your post is bad and don't know How to answer it correctly :|

Comment: No! We say it's bad because that's what it is! According to Stack Overflows Guidelines, you should not and shall not post questions which ask for code, tutorials, off-site resource, etc. Thereby the question is okay if it has an actual coding related problem in it! I don't see any code in the question, do you? I don't see any actual coding problem in the question, do you? No you don't because it's a bad question! AGAIN, try to read the [help/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page, about which question you should and shouldn't ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial with the full code needed.

http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/